# MS Access database management: prompting user for new table name

Tags: database, ms-access

I created a make table query and a rename macro that renames the table after it has been created. I want to create a dialog box that prompts for the new table name. Is this possible and how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better to use a VB sub which edit's the query def's SQL property, in other words change the tablename in the make table SQL statement before executing it e.g:

```
Public Sub MakeTable()

Dim strNewTableName As String
Dim Qdef As QueryDef

    strNewTableName = InputBox("Please enter the table name")

    If strNewTableName & "" = "" Then Exit Sub 'No table name has been given

    Set Qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MakeTableQueryName")

    Qdef.SQL = "SELECT bla, bla INTO " & strNewTableName & " WHERE etc"

    CurrentDb.Execute "MakeTableQueryName"

    Set Qdef = Nothing

End Sub
```

There is now no need to run a seperate Macro afterwards.